# An exercise on convex decreasing function properties

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

A function f$(x)$ defined for $x\geq0$. It is positive, decreasing, convex and log-convex: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log[f(x)]>0$,  $f(0)<1$. Can we prove that $f''(x)x+f'(x)>0$ for sufficiently large $x$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{d^2\log{f(x)}}{dx^2}$ or $\log{f''(x)}$?

Comment: Perhaps you can share your own thoughts on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

We just have to show that
$$ x+\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}>0 \tag{1}$$
holds for any $x$ big enough.

We have that $g\triangleq \log f$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ is negative, decreasing and convex, so $g'=\frac{f'}{f}$ is negative and increasing. Since $f'=f g'$, we have $f'' = f'g'+f g'' $. Now $(1)$ is equivalent to:

$$ (-g'(x))+\frac{g''(x)}{(-g'(x))}>\frac{1}{x}. \tag{2}$$
Let $h\triangleq -\frac{1}{g'}$. Then $h$ is positive and increasing, and we have to prove that for any $x$ big enough
$$ h < (1+h')\, x \tag{3}$$
holds. By setting $v(t)\triangleq h(e^t)$, this is the same as proving that any positive increasing function $v:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfies:
$$ v(t)-v'(t) < e^t \tag{4}$$
for any $t$ big enough. Since the solution of the ODE
$$ v(t) - v'(t) = K e^t $$
for $K\geq 1$ is given by $v(t) = (v(0)-K t)e^t$, the positivity of $v(t)$ gives that $(4)$ holds for any $t>v(0)$, hence $(1)$ holds for any
$$ x > \exp\left(-\frac{f}{f'}(1)\right).$$

Comment: The function $$g(x) =\frac{1}{x^{100}} $$ is strictly positive but it is not true that $$g(x)>\frac{1}{x}$$ for sufficiently large $x.$

Comment: @FisiaiLusia: you are clearly right, but in this context "strictly positive" means "greater or equal than a positive constant". Updating.

Comment: If you take $f(x) =(x+2)^{-1}$ then $g'(x)=-(x+2)^{-1}$ and $\sqrt{g''(x)} =\sqrt{2}(x+2)^{-1}$ which is not strictly positive in the sense you are talking about.

Comment: @FisiaiLusia: Ok, this answer needs serious fixing.

Comment: I meant by log convexity that f"f-(f')^2>0.
Thanks a lot for for your inputs, I have to understand the proof proposed. Actually, a function can aprroaches either zero or a positive constabt as x->+Infinity. A proof for either case would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If $f=e^k$ is decreasing and log convex on $(0,\infty)$ we are asked to prove that there exists $x_0$ such that
$$xk'^2(x)+(xk'(x))'\geq 0$$ for $x>x_0.$ To study this, we use the fact that $k'$ is increasing and negative. Therefore we can write
$$k'(x)=-C-\int_{x}^{\infty}k''(t)dt$$ with $C\geq 0.$ Now
$$I=xk'^2(x)+(xk'(x))'=x\left(\int_x^{\infty}k''(t)dt\right)^2+(xC-1)C+(2Cx-1)\int_{x}^{\infty}k''(t)dt+xk''(x)$$ which is positive if $x>1/C$ and $C>0$.

If $C=0$ then $$I=\left(x\int_x^{\infty}k''(t)dt-1\right)\left(\int_x^{\infty}k''(t)dt\right)+xk''(x).$$ It is negative if for instance $k''(t)=1/4t^2$ say for $t>1.$